# How to resize content when NavBar height changes

Tags: html, css

I have a page with content and the height is set to 100%. This works great.

Now, I want to add a toolbar at the top.  However, the toolbar is 50px height So when it is added, I get scrollbars on the page to account for the 50px.

How do I add the toolbar and not get scrollbars?

I have tried setting padding of the height of the toolbar to the content area.  This works until the toolbar changes size.

For example, if the screen is narrow, the toolbar changes accordingly. I need to be able to determine this event and then set the padding accordingly.

Is there a way to do this?  Or another way of resolving?

The page is a Single Page app, and it works best with no scrollbars.

There are also several themes, and some themes have a larger toolbar as set by the CSS that can change at runtime.  So again, I need to be able to detect changes in the size of the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Typescript that I came up with.

```
constructor() {
        this.setContentHeight();
        $(window).resize(() => this.setContentHeight());
    }

    setContentHeight() {
        let headerFooterHeight = $("#navBar").height() + $("#entityShellFooter").height();
        let browserWindowHeight = $(window).height();
        let contentHeight = browserWindowHeight - headerFooterHeight;
        $("#entityShellContent").height(contentHeight);
    }
```

and the HTML

```
    <header id="navBar">NavBar</header>

    <div id="entityShellContent">
            Content
    </div>

    <div id="entityShellFooter" >
        Status
    </div>
```